# spring-boot without @SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am attempting to migrate a spring, non-boot, app to a boot app.  The current one builds a war file. Following [these](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) instructions, I am walking through the steps to migrate.

I am finding that the @SpringBootApplication annotation forces a lot of things to fail. For instance, it tries to auto config security when I really need the existing xml security config to remain as is.  I found that I can override @EnableAutoConfiguration and exclude configuration classes (.i.e. SecurityAutoConfiguration.class). But I am finding it is doing this a great deal for the items I already have on my classpath.  I decided it would be better to remove @SpringBootApplication and replace it with just @Configuration, @ComponentScan and @ImportResource to load my original context xml. The class extends SpringBootServletInitializer so that I can register my custom servlets and filters.

What I have found, it now no longer knows to load the application.yml or bootstrap.yml. What triggers auto configuration of these files? Do I fall back to loading with the traditional properties placeholder configurers?  I want to avoid this as the next step is to hook it up to spring cloud config to centralize the management of the application configuration.

Answer (score 16):

`@SpringBootApplication` is a alternative for `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`.

Probably you want use `@Configuration` + `@ComponentScan`. If you want load xml configuration you can use: `@ImportResource` annotation.

If you want use autoconfiguration, but you can disable a few auto configurations, eg:

`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`

Details:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html
- http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-configuration-classes.html
- http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html